# InDesign not seeing Helvetica

Tags: adobe-indesign, font-management

OK, so I've got InDesign CS6.
Works well, all Fonts normally work, they're installed in Library/Application Support/Adobe/Fonts.

Apart from Helvetica, that is. It doesn't show up in the Fonts list if it's not in the Fonts folder of InDesign CS6, and even then, when it is in the fonts folder, only Helvetica is listed, despite the following derivatives being available:

Helvetica Oblique
Helvetica Bold
Helvetica Bold Oblique
Helvetica Light
Helvetica Light Oblique
Helvetica Roman
Helvetica

All fonts show in the Recently Used fonts list, but not in the fonts list itself (btw, previews of fonts are turned off to speed up InDesign).

I am on OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Why is this, and what could be causing it??
Strange, as I have no duplicates... the system fonts folder is as normal, so why is this?

Advice is appreciated!

Comment: Do you use a font-management software?

Comment: @Kaspar : No, all fonts go into the /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Fonts folder.

Comment: You did Install them trough a double-click right?

Comment: Sounds like it's conflicting with a system font. There is a Helvetica.dfont file that the OS uses.

Comment: Which version of Helvetica is that? I use Helvetica Neue on Maverics and InDesign CS6 and without problems.